# repeating html tag dynamically in div after a particular height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to repeat particular `HTML` element in a `div` after a particular height.

Consider we have a `div` and we want to add a `<span>` tag after every 50px height of `div.`

How can we achieve this?

I have tried this code.

```
<html>
<head>

<script>

function test() {
   var length = document.getElementById('lc').style.length;


    var element = document.createElement("div");
    element.setAttribute("id", "break");
    element.style.border
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello how are you'));
    document.getElementById('lc').appendChild(element);



}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<input id="filter" type="text" placeholder="Enter your filter text here.." onkeyup = "test()" />

<div id="lc" style="background: blue; height: 150px; width: 150px;
}" onclick="test();">  
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

The thing is on which basis i can repeat loop for this code

Comment: Add code that you tried

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.parent > *{
    display:block;
    height:50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
 }
</style>

<div classname="parent">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<script>

function test() {
var length = document.getElementById('lc').style.length;


    var element = document.createElement("div");
    element.setAttribute("id", "break");
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello how are you'));
    element.style.height = "50px";
    element.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('lc').appendChild(element);
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<input id="filter" type="text" placeholder="Enter your filter text here.." onkeyup = "test()" />

<div id="lc" style="background: #999;min-height:150px;width: 150px;" onclick="test();">  
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like that?

Here I'm adding a `div` for every 50px in the area (read my comments in the code).

**IMPORTANT:** you can completely ignore the `eventListener`. That part is just so the script recalculates the amount of spans needed after resizing the window.

```js
// Adding event listener
window.addEventListener("resize", magic);
// Running the function once so you don't have to resize the window
magic();
function magic() {
  // Clear the last elements
  while(area.firstChild) area.removeChild(area.firstChild);
  // Get the needed amout of spans needed
  let count = Math.floor(area.clientHeight / 50);
  // Adding a span for each 50px
  for(let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   let span = document.createElement("span");
     span.className = "spans";
      span.innerText = "Span WOHOO :D";
    area.appendChild(span);
  }
}
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#area {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.spans {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="area">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Have a nice day, Elias :)